# Load a Tabbarcontroller when button is clicked

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitabbarcontroller, xcode8

Im doing an application which is a tab bar controller app with tab bar items (Search, Login, More). After successful login of user tab bar changes to (Search, Account, More) with a Logout button in More. The problem is when Logout is clicked it should load `SearchViewController` and if again Login is clicked in tab bar the corresponding Login page doesn't show. It shows a black screen.

```
@IBAction func btnLogOutClicked(_ sender: UIButton) 
{
    let hm = SearchVC()
    let tabOneBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Search", image: UIImage(named: "TabHome.png"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "TabHome.png"))
    hm.tabBarItem = tabOneBarItem

    let lgn = LoginVC()
    let tabOneBarItem1 = UITabBarItem(title: "Login", image: UIImage(named: "tabAcc.png"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "tabAcc.png"))
    lgn.tabBarItem = tabOneBarItem1

    let mropt = MoreVC()
    mropt.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .more, tag: 2)

    let controllers = [hm, lgn, mropt]
    self.tabBarController?.viewControllers = controllers
    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
}
```

How would I make a tab bar controller display when Logout is clicked and clicking the tab bar item should display corresponding view controller.

Comment: SearchVC , LoginVC and MoreVC are inside IB ??

Comment: @Honey -  To avoid more condition and manage more complex structure prefer to change `rootViewControlloer` of window for logIn user and Logout user.

Comment: @Sh_Khan SearchVC , LoginVC and MoreVC are three separate viewcontrollers connected to tabbarcontroller in storyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load every vc like this after giving each one a storyboard identifier

```
let hm = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchVC") as! SearchVC
```

This

```
let hm = SearchVC()
```

Is used when the vc is created programmatically , and it's the main reason for black screen as the vc is loaded without it's layout

Comment: Wow ! That's amazing.. You saved my day ! Thanq buddy

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to load view of view controllers:

- from nib files (use [public init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621359-init))
- from storyboards (use [UIStoryboard](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistoryboard) to instantiate view controller)
- load it directly (usually programmatically) by overriding [loadView()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview)

The default init method such as SearchVC() will call init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil) for you. What's going on in this case is [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621487-nibname).

You have to use only first two option to load view from nib or storyboard correctly.

View Management is [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller) to see more.